# Expected Array: When I Try to Get Selected value of multi select combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm trying to make my code as flexible as possible. So i'm making my button function place in the varibles and call a different function to add in the logic. The problem is when I get to the day varible i'm finding it hard to store the information properly. I think it's a syntax issue I'm just not understanding yet.

```
If chkRetiree = True Then

    stepQuery = "Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                            "Where (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                                            "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                                            "AND (Retiree = True)"
    monday = chkMonR.Value
    tuesday = chkTuesR.Value
    wednesday = chkWedR.Value
    thursday = chkThursR.Value
    friday = chkFriR.Value
    day = "lstRetiree"

    Call stepUpdater
    'Call Initialize

End If
```

And here is the function that should grab the values of the variables

```
   For i = 0 To 32
        If day(i).Selected Then 'This is where the error happens

            rsStepCalendar(i).Value = rsStepCalendar(i).Value

        End If
   Next
```

Thanks a ton in advanced. Any help is much appreciated!

Full Code__________________________

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database
Dim monday As String
Dim tuesday As String
Dim wednesday As String
Dim thursday As String

Private Sub btnNewContact_Click()
    '        If lstDateWeek.Selected(i - 1) Then
    '
    '           RsStep("3" & i).Value = True

    Dim header As Integer

    header = Forms!frmContactsEdit!txtHeader.Value

    If chkActive = True Then
        stepQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblStepCalendar " & _
                    "WHERE (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                    "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                    "AND (Active = True)"

        monday = chkMonA.Value
        tuesday = chkTuesA.Value
        wednesday = chkWedA.Value
        thursday = chkThursA.Value
        friday = chkFriA.Value
        day = "lstActive"

        Call stepUpdater
        'Call Initialize
    End If

    If chkRetiree = True Then
        stepQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblStepCalendar " & _
                    "WHERE (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                    "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                    "AND (Retiree = True)"
        monday = chkMonR.Value
        tuesday = chkTuesR.Value
        wednesday = chkWedR.Value
        thursday = chkThursR.Value
        friday = chkFriR.Value
        day = "lstRetiree"
        Call stepUpdater
        'Call Initialize
    End If

    If chkCobra = True Then
        stepQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblStepCalendar " & _
                    "WHERE (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                    "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                    "AND (Cobra = True)"
        monday = chkMonC.Value
        tuesday = chkTuesC.Value
        wednesday = chkWedC.Value
        thursday = chkThursC.Value
        friday = chkFriC.Value
        day = "lstCobra"

        Call stepUpdater
        'Call Initialize
    End If
End Sub

Dim friday As String
Dim day As String
Dim stepQuery As String
Dim i As Integer

Public Sub stepUpdater()
    'Call Initialize
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset((stepQuery), dbOpenDynaset)

    If rsStepCalendar.EOF Then
        rsStepCalendar.AddNew
        rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value = monday
        rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value = tuesday
        rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value = wednesday
        rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value = thursday
        rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value = friday
        For i = 0 To 32
            If day(i).Selected Then
                rsStepCalendar(i).Value = rsStepCalendar(i).Value
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox ("Record Added")
        rsStepCalendar.Update
    Else
        If chkMonA <> rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value Then
            rsStepCalendar.Edit
            rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value = monday
            rsStepCalendar.Update
        End If

        If chkTuesA <> rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value Then
            rsStepCalendar.Edit
            rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value = tuesday
            rsStepCalendar.Update
        End If

        If chkWedA <> rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value Then
            rsStepCalendar.Edit
            rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value = wednesday
            rsStepCalendar.Update
        End If

        If chkThursA <> rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value Then
            rsStepCalendar.Edit
            rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value = thursday
            rsStepCalendar.Update
        End If

        If chkFriA <> rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value Then
            rsStepCalendar.Edit
            rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value = friday
            rsStepCalendar.Update
        End If

        For i = 0 To 32
            If day <> rsStepCalendar(i).Value Then
                rsStepCalendar.Edit
                rsStepCalendar(i).Value = rsStepCalendar(i).Value
                rsStepCalendar.Update
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Set rsStepCalendar = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your entire code?

Comment: Sure thing! I edited the comment above.

Comment: `Dim day As String` and then line `day(i).Selected` what do you mean by it?

Comment: I'm trying to loop through a multi select list box to get only the selected values into the database. The reason I am setting it as a variable is because I want to reuse that code for every if clause in the click function. Let me know if you need any more info! :D

Comment: Selected(i) is a method that would return a boolean value if a listbox item is selected. This is only to assume that your listbox is day. You're using it the wrong way. Day.Selected(i)

Comment: Is there a way I can throw the name of a listbox in a variable and call that later on. What if I call day as object and put the name of the list box in there?

Comment: You don't need to do actually. If you have added the listbox in your form manually. You can call like UserForm1.ListBox1

Comment: @HansUp Let me try and clear things up for ya. I've added a picture to the form that code is attached to. The user presses save an it runs the button click function in he code above. Depending on which check box is checked it should update either active retiree or cobra. The problem is when I get into the list boxes. I want the sub routine to run a max of 3 times. First it will run through active(this is why i'm changing the listbox names) then retiree then cobra. The issue is that it's turning into a chore to name the list variable to change. I need it this way so i'm only using 1 sub routine

Comment: Sorry it's kinda hard to explain hah. let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: I have a doubt that your table structure has a minimum of 32 columns each for the day of the month, please tell me this is not the case.

Comment: @PaulFrancis This is the case. Unfortunately, for reporting we need to have it like this. I know what your thinking and my first attempt was to have only 7 table columns but my boss wants to go a different direction.